# 【IOS】Monitor volume key, causing multiple calls

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to do some operations by clicking the volume button. I can do this in the following ways

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(volumeChangeNotification:)name:@"SystemVolumeDidChange" object:nil];

 - (void)volumeChangeNotification:(NSNotification *)notification {
  //do something
 }
```

But I found a puzzling phenomenon. Click the volume key once, and the monitoring event will be called twice. I try to delete the listener at the end of the listener function ，like this

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(volumeChangeNotification:)name:@"SystemVolumeDidChange" object:nil];

- (void)volumeChangeNotification:(NSNotification *)notification {
//do something
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"SystemVolumeDidChange" object:nil];
}
```

Then I turn on the monitor after 1 second, but it also doesn't work. What should I do？thanks verymuch

Comment: Where you put code of `addObserver:self` ?

Comment: in viewDidLoad  Like this : [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(volumeChangeNotification:)name:@"SystemVolumeDidChange" object:nil];

Comment: Do you remove it in `viewDidDisappear` or this experience happens while you open the the container vc for the first time ?

Comment: This may not be my problem, but the system has automatically called it twice. You can write a monitor and try it yourself  。In fact, I just want to know how to stop his two calls,thank you very much